# how to overwrite button's non-hover state colour to grey, but when hover button show the colour (with css framework)

Tags: css, hover, semantic-ui

I'm using semantic, they've colours class as below.

```
<button class='ui red button'> hover me to change red </button>
```

It show a red button with different shade when :active :hover and default state.

However I want the class colours only show on :hover state;
when not hover the button is overwrite **grey** colour.

Can this be done by adding one CSS class?

*note: I don't want to duplicate every semantic colours class to achieve this result*

Comment: you can set the background color of button into grey. Then when hover it will change the background color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

```css
.button:not(:hover) {
  color: white;
  background: green;
}

.button {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button class='ui red button'> hover me to change red </button>
```

Comment: Genius, I didn't know :not(:hover) can be used together in this way :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. Add one more class to the button.

```
<button class='ui red button hover-red'> hover me to change red </button>

.hover-red{
background: #ddd !important;
}

.hover-red:hover{
background-color: #E75859 !important;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rp0cd0me/

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite button's non-hover state colour to grey, try this-

```
button.red.button{background-color:grey;background:gray;}
```